# IF statement have an issue. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with if statement in my simple program.

```
var kripta = "sveta";
var vatra = "kralj";
var predstava = "odlicno";

if ( (kripta=="sveta") && (vatra=="kralj") && (predstava=="odlicno")){
        document.write="<p>Ja volim sebe</p>";
}else {
    function mojaFunkcija(){
        alert="Ja imam para!"
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: why that function inside the else block????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your function like: `mojaFunkcija();` in order to execute it.
Also use other methods of inserting HTML content instead of document.write (which is bad practice).

```
var kripta = "sveta";
var vatra = "kralj";
var predstava = "odlicno";

function mojaFunkcija(){
    alert("Ja imam para!");
}

if ( (kripta=="sveta") && (vatra=="kralj") && (predstava=="odlicno")){
   document.body.innerHTML = "<p>Ja volim sebe</p>";
}else {
   mojaFunkcija();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't mean to have that function declaration there, and if you want to use `document.write` or `alert`, they are functions that you call rather than assigning them values.

```
if ( (kripta=="sveta") && (vatra=="kralj") && (predstava=="odlicno") ) {
    document.write("<p>Ja volim sebe</p>");
} else {
    alert("Ja imam para!");
}
```